# vnext build for .net core using dotnet command

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, tfs, nuget, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to create a CI build using TFS 2015, and our application was created with Visual Studio 2017 .Net Core 2.1

Using command line, I'm executing:

```
dotnet publish --no-restore
```

But I'm encountering `Nuget` error.

> ...project.assets.json' not found. Run a NuGet package restore to generate this file.

Currently, my nuget packages are checked-in on my source control and I provided it on my `Nuget.Config`. This way, I do not need to download nuget every build (also some limitations on proxy)

```
<add key="globalPackagesFolder" value="..\packages" />
```

Anyone know how to fix this?

Any other ways to build .net core application is welcome as well. (MSBuild, etc).

Comment: The error basically means that the project.assets.json file is not being generated which is required for Nuget.exe. Since you have all packages checked in, you should be doing a restore since its locally available it won't go to Nuget.org to download any packages. Instead of checking in all packages locally, create a common shared location. That way you will be able to share the common packages among multiple projects instead of checking them in TFS. Update the Nuget config to look at this shared location as the source folder and then do a Dotnet Publish

Answer (score 0):

You need to use MSbuild 15.0 to run .net core application. Check the blog below:

https://www.dotnetcatch.com/2017/11/15/building-net-core-and-net-standard-projects-in-tfs-2015/

Answer (score 0):

The project.assets.json file is generated by Nuget.exe, so you need to add NuGet restore task to build definition.

Also, if the packages already existing, it won't download the packages again during NuGet restore task.